# Extracting a class file from a Business Logic Layer DLL file and modifying it as a separate class.

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, dll

I've recently taken over working on a .NET site. The original developer is uncontactable so that I don't have the source files,  all I have are the aspx files and their corresponding .cs code behind files. The business logic is compiled in a file called BLL.dll

Up until now this has been fine, as I've only needed to make fairly superficial changes, that could be done by editing the .aspx or codebehind files, however, no I need to make a small change to a method contained in BLL.dll file. I've been able to decompile the files using DotPeek and can copy the code from the class file I want to edit. From what I've read, recompiling decompiled DLL files isn't advised (if even possible at all).

My question is, can a single file from this DLL be used as a standalone class file in my App_Code folder, or will there be dependencies within the DLL that can't be accessed by a standalone class.

I've tried creating it as a standalone class file, but am getting the error that 'System.Transactions' could not be found, although it seems to be working when it's referenced in the compiled BLL.dll file.

I'm a novice at .NET, so please excuse my ignorance.

Thanks

Comment: You are not aware for how much trouble you signed up... either get the source code or decompile EVERYTHING to create a new solution, compile, test and re-deploy that. Don't even try to fiddle the way you do now, you're doomed, specially if you're a novice at .net.

Comment: Just as I feared, looks like I'll have an easier time trying to hunt down the original developer. Thanks for the positive outlook :P